# Observer pattern with different notifications

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to create an observer pattern that the subject notifies the observers with different notifications.

Normally in observer pattern implementations you can see only one method called `notify` where it notifies the observers that something happened and has a kind of inversion where the observer holds the pointer of the subject and ask the subject for something when it's notified.

I'm implementing this a little different, where the subject attaches the observers and notify all of them without the needed of holding the pointer of a subject inside of the observers. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class ObserverEvents
{
public:
    virtual addSomethingOne(int) = 0;
    virtual addSomethingTwo(float) = 0;
};

class Observer : public ObserverEvents
{
public:
    Observer();
    ~Observer();

    virtual addSomethingOne(int) {}
    virtual addSomethingTwo(float) {}
};

class Subject : public ObserverEvents
{
public:
    Subject() {}

    ~Subject()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); ++i)
        {
            delete observers[i];
        }
    }

    void attach(Observer * observer)
    {
        observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    virtual addSomethingOne(int something)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); ++i)
        {
            observers[i].addSomethingOne(something);
        }
    }

    virtual addSomethingTwo(float something)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); ++i)
        {
            observers[i].addSomethingTwo(something);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Observer *> observers;
};

class FooObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    BarObserver() {}
    ~BarObserver() {}

    addSomethingOne(int something)
    {
        // do something with something
    }

    addSomethingTwo(float something)
    {
        // do something with something
    }
};

class BarObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    BizObserver() {}
    ~BizObserver() {}

    addSomethingOne(int something)
    {
        // do something with something
    }

    addSomethingTwo(float something)
    {
        // do something with something
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{
    Subject subject;
    subject.attach(new FooObserver());
    subject.attach(new BarObserver());

    return 0;
}
```

The only thing I'm concern is if I'm not broking any design principle like the Open and Closed or something similar, and also if I need to add a new notification I need to implement in all other classes. (which is painful - imagine 10 observers or even more).

I was thinking in make this different, create only one interface and then I can inherit it creating other notifications but there's a problem, how can the observers determine what each different type of notification are?

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Notifier
{
public:
    Notifier() {}
    ~Notifier() {}

    virtual int getInt() const = 0;
};

class FooNotifier
{
public:
    FooNotifier() {}
    ~FooNotifier() {}

    int getInt() const
    {
        return 10;
    }
};

class BarNotifier
{
public:
    BarNotifier() {}
    ~BarNotifier() {}

    int getInt() const
    {
        return 50;
    }
};

class Observer : public ObserverEvents
{
public:
    Observer();
    ~Observer();

    virtual receive(Notifier *) = 0;
};

class Subject : public ObserverEvents
{
public:
    Subject() {}

    ~Subject()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); ++i)
        {
            delete observers[i];
        }
    }

    void attach(Observer * observer)
    {
        observers.push_back(observer);
    }

    virtual notify(Notifier * notification)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); ++i)
        {
            observers[i].receive(notification);
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Observer *> observers;
};

class FooObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    BarObserver() {}
    ~BarObserver() {}

    receive(Notifier * notification)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

class BarObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    BizObserver() {}
    ~BizObserver() {}

    receive(Notifier * notification)
    {
        // ...
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const * argv[])
{
    Subject subject;
    subject.attach(new FooObserver());
    subject.attach(new BarObserver());

    subject.notify(new FooNotifier());
    subject.notify(new BarNotifier());

    return 0;
}
```

The implementation is just an example, I know that I can be using smart pointers, deleting raw pointers and doing things better, but it's JUST an example of implementation.

The problem with this new approach is that I will need to know if `Notifier`'s API in order to use it inside of the Observer, to call `getInt`.

How can I do this, what is the best way for doing that? How can I send different notifications to the observers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Virtual Destructor

When a class has virtual functions it is usually an indication that it also needs a virtual destructor (assuming the base class).

```
class ObserverEvents
{
public:
    virtual addSomethingOne(int) = 0;
    virtual addSomethingTwo(float) = 0;
};
```

The reason for this is that it will usually be deleted via a pointer to the base class (if dynamically allocated). If the destructor is not virtual only the base class will be destroyed. By making it virtual the destructor of the most derived class will be destroyed. Note: It is UB to do this delete with a virtual destructor.

### Memory Management (Rule of 3)

If you define the Copy Constructor Assignment operator or destructor and you do some form of memory management then you probably need to define all three. This is called the rule of three.

```
class Subject : public ObserverEvents
{
public:    
    ~Subject()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < observers.size(); ++i)
        {
            delete observers[i];
        }
    }
```

This is because the compiler will generate default versions of these. Under normal situations the default versions work. But when you start messing with memory management they usually need to be defined to work together (deep copy problem).

In this case Subject has a compiler generated copy constructor and assignment operator. These will do a shallow copy of the object. This will result in both vectors holding the same pointers and the destructor of these objects will delete the objects (resulting in a double delete).

```
  {
       Subject   x;
       // Add some Listeners to x.

       Subject   y(x);   // y now contains all the pointers in x
                         // because the std::vector<> copy constructor is invoked.
                         // to copy the vector.

   } // y is destroyed.
     // Which calls delete on all the objects in the vector.
     // Then x is destroyed.
     // Which will call delete on the same pointers that were stored in y.
```

### Memory Management (Ownership Semantics)

In modern C++ it is unusual to pass around RAW pointers. You would normally pass by reference or a smart pointer (or potentially a container).

```
void attach(Observer * observer)
{
    observers.push_back(observer);
}
```

This is because pointers do not have an indication of ownership. Ownership is the concept of who is responsible for deleting the object. So from your interface I can not tell if the pointer I am passing you means you are taking ownership or not. I have to open your class and look at the destructor to see that you are expecting to take ownership of the object.

```
 // Example 1:
 Observer    x;
 Subject     y;
 y.attach(&x);  // Broken you will delete my automatic object.

 // Example 2:
 Observer*   x  = new Observer;
 Subject     y;
 y.attach(x);

 // Use x in some way.
 delete x;
 // Also bad.
```

To show ownership in this case I would use std::unqiue_ptr. This is an object that takes a pointer and indicates that it ownes the pointer.

```
void attach(std::unique_ptr<Observer> observer)
{
    observers.push_back(observer.release());
}
```

Comment: Even though my question was just an example you opened my eyes about some things, I really appreciate that. Thank you very much - As you can see it's on hold as off-topic then I opened the same topic in Stack Exchange and there I received some answers as well but nothing was solved, maybe reading you can help there too (read the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833920/observer-pattern-with-different-notifications/26834487